# Why doesnt the settings save when I try to do it through code?

Tags: c#, .net, settings

So I wrote this quick example to test out what it's like saving data to the Application Settings, but it seems as if there are some issues saving the actual data because when I debug it and run it on my PC it saves the data and it acts as it should, but if I send the EXE to my friend after I already executed it (meaning that it should have a string saved in the Settings already) it acts as if there is nothing there and goes straight to `Lock`

Why does it behave like that? Do I need to send some config file with it?

```
        if (HWID.HasKey())
        {
            if (HWID.CompareKey())
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you're not authorized to use this app.");
            Close();
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Software has been registered.");
        HWID.Lock();
```

And the HWID class

```
class HWID
{

    public static bool HasKey()
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.ID))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void Lock()
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.ID))
        {
            ManagementClass managClass = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection managCollec = managClass.GetInstances();

            foreach (ManagementObject managObj in managCollec)
            {
                var cpuInfo = managObj.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
                Settings.Default.ID = cpuInfo;
                Settings.Default.Save();
                Settings.Default.Reload();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public static bool CompareKey()
    {
        var managClass = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
        var managCollec = managClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (var managObj in managCollec)
        {
            var cpuInfo = managObj.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
            if (cpuInfo == Settings.Default.ID)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you think Settings are a part of the EXE?  its not, it is just a file

Comment: Is there no way to embedd it into the exe? With something similar to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/